# Basic Async/Await pattern?

Tags: dart

I'm trying to figure out a async/await problem in Dart.  I am calling a short sequence of http fetches and wanting to await them all.  I created this sample code to demonstrate the problem.

I would expect to see "begin test" followed by each of the downloads starting in order.  Then each of the downloads would finish in random order and then I would see "end test".  However I am seeing "end test" before any of the downloads even begin.

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class AsyncTest {
  final _resourceList = [
    {
      'name': 'Test 1',
      'url': 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
    },
    {
      'name': 'Test 2',
      'url': 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments'
    },
    {
      'name': 'Test 3',
      'url': 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums'
    },
    {
      'name': 'Test 4',
      'url': 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos'
    },
    {
      'name': 'Test 5',
      'url': 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'
    },
  ];

  void beginTest() async {
    print('begin test');
    await getAll();
    print('end test');
  }

  Future<void> getAll() async {
    _resourceList.forEach((resource) async {
      print('begin ${resource['name']}');

      final response = await http.get(resource['url']);

      print('end ${resource['name']}');
    });
  }
}
```

Here is the output.

```
flutter: begin test
flutter: end test
flutter: begin Test 1
flutter: begin Test 2
flutter: begin Test 3
flutter: begin Test 4
flutter: begin Test 5
flutter: end Test 1
flutter: end Test 5
flutter: end Test 3
flutter: end Test 2
flutter: end Test 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would expect to see "begin test" followed by each of the downloads
>   starting in order. Then each of the downloads would finish in random
>   order and then I would see "end test". However I am seeing "end test"
>   before any of the downloads even begin.

That's because you are (accidentally) requesting the asynchronous calls to happen *after* `'end test'`:

```
Future<void> getAll() async {
  _resourceList.forEach((resource) async {
    print('begin ${resource['name']}');

    final response = await http.get(resource['url']);

    print('end ${resource['name']}');
  });
}
```

Specifically, your function is:

1. Entering the `getAll() function`
2. Invoking `_resourceList.forEach(...)`
3. Yielding to the micro-task loop
4. Exciting the `getAll()` function
5. In the next microtask, executing the body of the `async { ... }` callback

You have a few options. You could use likely [`Future.wait`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-async/Future/wait.html) or [`Future.forEach`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-async/Future/forEach.html) if you want to use a callback, but otherwise `for ...` will do what you wanted before exiting `getAll()` - the built-in [`for ...` loop will be transformed to completing the `Future` when you expect](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/language/await-async).

```
Future<void> getAll() async {
  for (var resource in _resourceList) {
    print('begin ${resource['name']}');

    final response = await http.get(resource['url']);

    print('end ${resource['name']}');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Help me understand why.  In your explanation step 3 "Yielding to the micro-task loop", where am I doing this?  Or is it that a List<>.forEach by its nature yields?  I have implemented your suggestion of using a regular for loop and it does indeed do what I was expecting.  I am accepting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `await` call inside `getAll()` allows the event loop to process a different path. So yes, it makes sense that all the early things (begin...) show up first, and the later things (end...) show up in an apparently random order.  This is the inherent nature of async programming.

Comment: That part is what I expected and hope to happen.  The fetches are independent and  essentially happening in parallel.  However the "end test" is happening before each of the individual tests end.  I want to make sure that my "await getAll()" actually waits until completion.

Answer (score 0):

`forEach(callback)` ignores the return value from `callback`.

If you use a `for` loop, `await` works as expected:

```
  Future<void> getAll() async {
    for(var resource in _resourceList) {
      print('begin ${resource['name']}');

      final response = await http.get(resource['url']);

      print('end ${resource['name']}');
    }
  }
```

alternatively to have the loop body execute concurrently, you can use

```
  Future<void> getAll() async {
    return Future.wait(_resourceList.map((resource) async {
      print('begin ${resource['name']}');

      final response = await http.get(resource['url']);

      print('end ${resource['name']}');
    }));
  }
```

With `map` the `Future`s returned from the callbacks are collected and when they are all completed (success or error), the returned `Future` will complete.